# Point of origin for text :imagettftext

Tags: php, imagettftext

I am using imagettftext function to write text on my image but the problem is when i set x,y postion to 0,0 in it does write text on top left of the image .

Is there any way to make my point of origin top left ??

Answer (score 0):

From the PHP Manual:

> The coordinates given by x and y will define the basepoint of the first character (roughly
>   the lower-left corner of the character). This is different from the imagestring(), where x
>   and y define the upper-left corner of the first character. For example, "top left" is 0, 0.

So if you want the origin point on top left you can use `imagestring()` or you can sum the letter height to the y point of the `imagettftext()` function.

To get the height of the letter you can use `imagettfbbox()` function:

```
$bbox = imagettfbbox ( $size , $angle , $fontfile , $text );
$y_offset = abs($bbox[7] - $bbox[1]);
imagettftext ( $image , $size , $angle , $x , $y + $y_offset , $color , $fontfile , $text );
```